# Spark task time variance extremely high, when data skew is not very high

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am running a query on a big job, involving a cross join and many window functions in Spark.

[image]

You can see the distribution of the task duration, the read/write size. There does not seem to be a huge data skew, however the task time variance is huge.

[image]

We can also see that almost all of the time is spent on "Executor  Computing time".

And Overall stage information below.

[image]

I originally thought this was data skew so I tweaked the partitions and it seems not to be an issue.

Could it be a problem with the source table partitioning?

EDIT: Code snippet below

```
WITH valid_ids AS (
    (
        SELECT 
            t1.id1,
            t1.id2
        FROM t1
        INNER JOIN
            t2
        ON t1.id1 = t2.id1
        GROUP BY t1.id1, t1.id2
        HAVING MAX(t2.date) >= CURRENT_DATE() - 2000
    )
    UNION 
    (
           SELECT 
            t3.id1,
            t3.id2
        FROM t3
        INNER JOIN
            t4
        ON t3.id1 = t4.id1
        GROUP BY t3.id1, t3.id2
        HAVING MAX(t4.date) >= CURRENT_DATE() - 2000
    )
),
gen_dates AS (
    (
        SELECT 
            vc.id1,
            vc.id2,
            t4.date
        FROM valid_ids vc
        LEFT JOIN t4
            ON vc.id1 = t4.id1
        LEFT JOIN t3
            ON vc.id1 = t3.id1
        WHERE t4.date >= t3.first_date
    )
    UNION
    (
        SELECT 
            vc.id1,
            vc.id2,
            t2.date
        FROM valid_ids vc
        LEFT JOIN t2
            ON vc.id1 = t2.id1
        LEFT JOIN t1
            ON vc.id1 = t1.id1
        WHERE t2.date >= t1.first_date
    )
),
exploded_dates AS (
    SELECT 
        EXPLODE(SEQUENCE(CURRENT_DATE() - 2000, CURRENT_DATE())) as activity_date
    FROM gen_dates
),
all_dates AS (
    (
        SELECT
            vc.id1,
            vc.id2,
            ex.date
        FROM valid_ids vc
        CROSS JOIN exploded_dates ex
    )
    UNION
    (
        SELECT 
            *
        FROM customer_dates
    )
),
base AS (
    ## Get some daily level features from joins on other source tables
),
all_date AS (
   ## this is all window functions over interval for example:
CAST(COALESCE(SUM(t3.feature1) OVER (PARTITION BY base.id1, base.id2 ORDER BY TIMESTAMP(base.date) RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 6 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), 0) as float) as feature1_last7,
        CAST(COALESCE(SUM(t3.feature1) OVER (PARTITION BY base.id1, base.id2 ORDER BY TIMESTAMP(base.date) RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 29 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), 0) as float) as feature1_last30,
     CAST(COALESCE(SUM(t3.feature1) OVER (PARTITION BY base.id1, base.id2 ORDER BY TIMESTAMP(base.date) RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 364 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), 0) as float) as feature1_last365,

...
)
```

Comment: Hi, hard to tell without more information on your code. From here, it looks like some records are longer than others to compute. Could that be the case? I think that it would help if you could share some sample data and enough code for us to understand what you are doing.

Comment: i gave some basic examples in the query above, not there are a lot of window functions, these are just an example. total query is quite large.